# Replace cell values when binding DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a problem with following code:

```
string  b = txtHouseNo.Text;
var familyMemberQry = from fmMbQry in smrtstObj.tblFamily
where fmMbQry.HouseNo == b
select new
{                              
    fmMbQry.SerialNo,
    fmMbQry.Name,
    fmMbQry.Sex,
    fmMbQry.MobileNo,
    fmMbQry.MaritulStatus
   }
 };
 dgvFamilyMembers.DataSource = familyMemberQry.ToList();
```

In this code `fmMbQry.Sex` returns boolean and `fmMbQry.MaritulStatus` returns selected index of a combobox as Integer.

I want to replace boolean by 'Male' and 'Female', and selected index by 'Single', 'Married', 'Divorced','Widower', 'Widow'.

Currently I get checkbox on sex column. I want replace this check box by Male or female, and in marital Status column have corresponding Selected Index of a  corresponding combo box.

Comment: you have to handle it in DataGridview Binding

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting to retrieve values of sex and martial status and binding directly to controls. then below code seems useful.

```
Sex = fmMbQry.Sex == 0 ? "Female" : "Male"
MaritualStatus =  fmMbQry.MaritulStatus == 1 ? "Single" : fmMbQry.MaritulStatus == 2 ? "Married" :  fmMbQry.MaritulStatus == 3 ? "Divorce" : fmMbQry.MaritulStatus == 4 && fmMbQry.Sex == 0 ? "Window" : "windower"
```

Comment: But I got the following error!!    Error:- 1 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int' @Raghu